# Proving $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + .... + n^3 = (1/4)n^4 + (1/2)n^3 + (1/4)n^2$ by induction.

Tags: induction

so I recently had some lessons in induction and I feel pretty comfortable with it, but there is just this one exercise that I for some reason can't figure out.

I got this so far:

$1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + .... + n^3 = \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{n^2}{4}$
is what I need to proof, I already did the $n = 1$ and the induction hypothesis step but after that I'm stuck.
I got the point where I used induction to replace the $n^3$ for the $\frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{n^2}{4}$ and made it all one big $\frac{p}{4}$ but I just can't get it to work.

If someone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The base case $n = 0$ is clearly true.

Assume the following is true
\begin{equation}
1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \ldots + n^3 = \frac{1}{4}n^4 + \frac{1}{2}n^3 + \frac{1}{4}n^2
\end{equation}
Let's prove
\begin{equation}
 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + .... + n^3 + (n+1)^3 = \frac{1}{4}n^4 + \frac{1}{2}n^3 + \frac{1}{4}n^2 + (n+1)^3
\end{equation}
The right hand side is

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
   \frac{1}{4}n^4 + \frac{1}{2}n^3 + \frac{1}{4}n^2 + (n+1)^3
   &= 
   \frac{1}{4}n^4 + \frac{1}{2}n^3 +\frac{1}{4}n^2 + n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
Now let's check if $$\frac{1}{4}n^4 + \frac{1}{2}n^3 + \frac{1}{4}n^2 + n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 = \frac{1}{4}(n+1)^4 + \frac{1}{2}(n+1)^3 + \frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2 \tag{1} $$
Expand each term on the RHS
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}(n+1)^4
=
\frac{1}{4}(n^4 + 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}(n+1)^3
=
\frac{1}{2}(n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2
 =
 \frac{1}{4}(n^2 + 2n + 1)
\end{equation}
Add all the above three terms and you should get the LHS in equation $(1)$